# Flutter SliverGrid childern inside CustomScrollView collapses after scrolling

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have SliverAppBar and SliverGrid inside CustomScrollView, on first run grid is showing fine,but if i scroll the page a  few times,grid item collapses to first position in SliverFrid, all items appear on top of each other.

i tried using NestedScrollView but same behavior is happening

`return Container(
          child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              expandedHeight: 400,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Text("TEXT"),
                background: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "TEXT",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverGrid.count(
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              children: [
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
            Text("ABC"),
        ],
            ),
          ]),
        );`

also i am not getting any error in console.

[image: when i run app this is shown, which is fine]

[image: atfer scrolling few time i get this]

UPDATE 1: It is only happening on my phone which Galaxy a3 2017 (a320f) android v8.1, works fine in emulator and nokia 5.

Comment: It is working fine for me.

Comment: i have added images, as you can see this is happening to me

Comment: it happens when you scroll the page a few times.